# How to Host node application in IIS?

Tags: node.js, iis, express, mean-stack, iisnode

I am developing an application in mean-stack. The only the difference is that I want to host my application in IIS rather than express.js. Is it possible or feasible to do so? What are possible advantages and disadvantages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be possible: [Hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). That site even mentions some benefits. To be honest, I have no first hand experience (or need) to run Node on IIS.

Comment: Thanks for  the reply

Comment: My condition: i need serve APP and API in same server port 80. But one is http://www.app.com/ and other http://api.app.com/. Using IIS it is possible.

Comment: @SergioCabral IIS is not required for that.